# How to apply a CSS filter to a background image

Tags: css, background-image, css-filters

I have a JPEG file that I'm using as a background image for a search page, and I'm using CSS to set it because I'm working within [Backbone.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backbone.js) contexts:

```
background-image: url("whatever.jpg");
```

I want to apply a CSS 3 blur filter *only* to the background, but I'm not sure how to style just that one element. If I try:

```
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
```

just underneath `background-image` in my CSS, it styles the whole page, rather than just the background. Is there a way to select just the image and apply the filter to that? Alternatively, is there a way to just turn the blur off for every other element on the page?

Comment: Blur only a part of an image: https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/gjMEWm

Answer (score 594, accepted):

You will have to use two different containers, one for the background image and the other for your content.

In the example, I have created two containers, `.background-image` and `.content`.

Both of them are placed with `position: fixed` and `left: 0; right: 0;`. The difference in displaying them comes from the `z-index` values which have been set differently for the elements.

```css
.background-image {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjzQS.jpg');
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image"></div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam erat in ante malesuada, facilisis semper nulla semper. Phasellus sapien neque, faucibus in malesuada quis, lacinia et libero. Sed sed turpis tellus. Etiam ac aliquam tortor, eleifend
    rhoncus metus. Ut turpis massa, sollicitudin sit amet molestie a, posuere sit amet nisl. Mauris tincidunt cursus posuere. Nam commodo libero quis lacus sodales, nec feugiat ante posuere. Donec pulvinar auctor commodo. Donec egestas diam ut mi adipiscing,
    quis lacinia mauris condimentum. Quisque quis odio venenatis, venenatis nisi a, vehicula ipsum. Etiam at nisl eu felis vulputate porta.</p>
  <p>Fusce ut placerat eros. Aliquam consequat in augue sed convallis. Donec orci urna, tincidunt vel dui at, elementum semper dolor. Donec tincidunt risus sed magna dictum, quis luctus metus volutpat. Donec accumsan et nunc vulputate accumsan. Vestibulum
    tempor, erat in mattis fringilla, elit urna ornare nunc, vel pretium elit sem quis orci. Vivamus condimentum dictum tempor. Nam at est ante. Sed lobortis et lorem in sagittis. In suscipit in est et vehicula.</p>
</div>
```

[Matthew Wilcoxson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266375/matthew-wilcoxson) suggested implementation using `.content::before` to avoid a second div: https://codepen.io/akademy/pen/FlkzB

Comment: A slightly better way to do this is to use .content:before instead of the extra "background-image" markup. I updated the pen here : http://codepen.io/akademy/pen/FlkzB

Comment: Hi. What effect does blurring have on the performance? Does it make the page rendering significantly slower?

Comment: Also see [Backdrop filters](https://webkit.org/blog/3632/introducing-backdrop-filters/)

Comment: with the content:before solution you can't set the background-image dynamically in the element though? As per many needs of this kind to create images galleries etc @MatthewWilcoxson?

Answer (score 107):

Abolishing the need for an extra element, along with making the content fit within the document flow rather than being fixed/absolute like other solutions.

Achieved using

```css
.content {
  /* this is needed or the background will be offset by a few pixels at the top */
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.content::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;

  display: block;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjzQS.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

If you are interested in removing the white borders at the edges, use a width and height of `110%` and a left and top of `-5%`. This will enlarge your backgrounds a tad, but there should be no solid colour bleeding in from the edges.

```css
.content {
  /* this is needed or the background will be offset by a few pixels at the top */
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.content::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: -5%;
  left: -5%;
  right: -5%;
  z-index: -1;

  display: block;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjzQS.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  width: 110%;
  height: 110%;

  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: The limitation with this is that you can't manipulate pseudo elements in js. If you don't need to, then it's a good solve.

Comment: If you don't like the blurred white border you can increase the `width` and `height` to `110%` and then add an offset of `-5%` to `top` and `left` of the `content:before` class.

Comment: It's working for me, but I want that background image also to get scrolled when the user scrolls the page. The FIXED position is stopping that. How to get rid off this issue ?

Comment: Using `position: absolute` instead of position:fixed will have the same effect and prevent the background image from showing down the page.

Answer (score 93):

As stated in other answers this can be achieved with:

- A copy of the blurred image as the background.
- A pseudo element that can be filtered then positioned behind the content.

### You can also use [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

There is a supported property called `backdrop-filter`, and it is currently
supported in Chrome, Firefox, [Edge](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/9160189-backdrop-filters), Safari, and iOS Safari (see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter) for statistics).

From [Mozilla devdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter):

> The backdrop-filter property provides for effects like blurring or color shifting the area behind an element, which can then be seen through that element by adjusting the element's transparency/opacity.

See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter) for usage statistics.

You would use it like so.
If you do not want content inside to be blurred use the utility class `.u-non-blurred`

```css
.background-filter::after {
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px); /* Use for Safari 9+, Edge 17+ (not a mistake) and iOS Safari 9.2+ */
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px); /* Supported in all major browsers */

  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.background-filter {
  position: relative;
}

.background {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/62/Kermit_the_Frog.jpg');
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

/* Use for child content that should not be blurred */
.u-non-blurred {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="background background-filter">
  <h1 class="u-non-blurred">Kermit D. Frog</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Even if it doesn't work in all browsers, you get my vote for providing the spec-correct non-hack way to do this.

Comment: AFAIK this is a non standard feature, so there's no spec for it.

Comment: HEADS UP! In 2018 browser support has significantly dropped for this! Not supported in Edge, Firefox, or Chrome.

Comment: @protoEvangelion Seems that it will be available in Edge 16+, and I don't see any other browsers saying they won't implement this. Any facts to back up these claims?

Comment: @hitautodestruct According to caniuse.com IE, Edge 16, Firefox and Chrome do not support this by default at the moment. You are right that Edge 17+ supports this. Thanks for pointing that out. Cool answer though by the way, I sure do hope browsers implement this :)

Comment: Demo: https://codepen.io/simran/pen/VJmYPB
According to caniuse.com, Chrome 76 will support it by default (without flag).

Comment: `<div class="background background-filter"><h1>Unblurred content</h1></div>` seems to mess it up

Comment: November 2022: Supported in al major browsers.

Answer (score 27):

You need to re-structure your HTML in order to do this. You have to blur the whole element in order to blur the background. So if you want to blur only the background, it has to be its own element.

Answer (score 10):

The following is a simple solution for modern browsers in pure CSS with a 'before' pseudo element, like the solution from Matthew Wilcoxson.

To avoid the need of accessing the pseudo element for changing the image and other attributes in JavaScript, simply use `inherit` as the value and access them via the parent element (here `body`).

```
body::before {
    content: ""; /* Important */
    z-index: -1; /* Important */
    position: inherit;
    left: inherit;
    top: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background-image: inherit;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(8px);
}

body {
  background-image: url("xyz.jpg");
  background-size: 0 0;  /* Image should not be drawn here */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed; /* Or absolute for scrollable backgrounds */
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Do you have a working jsfiddle?

Answer (score 9):

Please check the below code:-

```css
.backgroundImageCVR{
    position:relative;
    padding:15px;
}
.background-image{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:url('https://i.imgur.com/5SZI6qZ.jpeg');
    background-size:cover;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -o-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);   
}
.content{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundImageCVR">
    <div class="background-image"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam erat in ante malesuada, facilisis semper nulla semper. Phasellus sapien neque, faucibus in malesuada quis, lacinia et libero. Sed sed turpis tellus. Etiam ac aliquam tortor, eleifend rhoncus metus. Ut turpis massa, sollicitudin sit amet molestie a, posuere sit amet nisl. Mauris tincidunt cursus posuere. Nam commodo libero quis lacus sodales, nec feugiat ante posuere. Donec pulvinar auctor commodo. Donec egestas diam ut mi adipiscing, quis lacinia mauris condimentum. Quisque quis odio venenatis, venenatis nisi a, vehicula ipsum. Etiam at nisl eu felis vulputate porta.</p>
      <p>Fusce ut placerat eros. Aliquam consequat in augue sed convallis. Donec orci urna, tincidunt vel dui at, elementum semper dolor. Donec tincidunt risus sed magna dictum, quis luctus metus volutpat. Donec accumsan et nunc vulputate accumsan. Vestibulum tempor, erat in mattis fringilla, elit urna ornare nunc, vel pretium elit sem quis orci. Vivamus condimentum dictum tempor. Nam at est ante. Sed lobortis et lorem in sagittis. In suscipit in est et vehicula.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `.content` tab in CSS change it to `position:absolute`. Otherwise, the page rendered won't be scrollable.

Answer (score 2):

The Specification introduced a new [`filter()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterCSSImageValue) function that you can use with background images like below:

```css
background: filter(url("whatever.jpg"), blur(5px));
```

> The `<filter()>` function takes two arguments. The first argument is an `<image>`. The second is a filter function list as specified for the CSS filter property. The function takes the  parameter and applies the filter rules, returning a processing image.

But there is no browser support for this: https://caniuse.com/css-filter-function. You can only test on Safari for now.

Answer (score 1):

Although all the solutions mentioned are very clever, all seemed to have minor issues or potential knock on effects with other elements on the page when I tried them.

In the end to save time I simply went back to my old solution: I used [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) and went to Effects, Gaussian Blur with a radius 5 to 10 pixels and just saved that as the page image.  :-)

HTML:

```
<body class="mainbody">
</body
```

CSS:

```
body.mainbody
{
    background: url('../images/myphoto.blurred.png');
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I finally got it working, but the solution is by no means straightforward! See here:

- [filter: blur(1px); doesn't work in firefox, IE, and opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803122/filter-blur1px-doesnt-work-in-firefox-ie-and-opera#40532319)

Comment: you download 2 imgs

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this is not a CSS-solution, but you can use the CDN Proton with `filter`:

```
body {
    background: url('https://i0.wp.com/IMAGEURL?w=600&filter=blurgaussian&smooth=1');
}
```

It is from https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/photon/api/#filter

Comment: Any slick ways to make this work for `localhost` while testing?

Comment: The blur amount for a large res image is way too subtle, how do I drastically increase the blur amount without it looking blocky? The width helps a little, but it looks too blocky if i blur too much

Answer (score 1):

All you actually need is "filter":

```
blur(«WhatEverYouWantInPixels»);"
```

```css
body {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#background {
    background-image: url('https://cdn2.geckoandfly.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/ios-11-3840x2160-4k-5k-beach-ocean-13655.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;

    /* START */
    /* START */
    /* START */
    /* START */

    /* You can adjust the blur-radius as you'd like */
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>

<p id="randomContent">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now this become even simpler and more flexible by using CSS GRID.You just have to overlap the blured background(imgbg) with the text(h2)

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="imgbg"></div>
 <h2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facilis enim
  aut rerum mollitia quas voluptas delectus facere magni cum unde?:)
 </h2>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.container {
        display: grid;
        width: 30em;
      }

.imgbg {
        background: url(bg3.jpg) no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
        grid-column: 1/-1;
        grid-row: 1/-1;
        filter: blur(4px);
      }


     .container h2 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        grid-column: 1/-1;
        grid-row: 1/-1;
        z-index: 2;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS grid is easier for me to understand. :)

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 6fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
  '. . .'
  '. content .'
  '. . .'; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.backbround {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  grid-area: 1/1/5/5;
  
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/aUhpEz3.jpg);
  filter: blur(5px);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.content {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  
  grid-area: content;
  display: flex;
  
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="backbround"></div>
  <div class="content"><h1>Hello World</h1></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for a [Material Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design) horizontal card layout with dynamic height and an image.

To prevent distortion of the image due to the dynamic height of the card, you could use a background placeholder image with blur to adjust for changes in height.

### Explanation

- The card is contained in a `<div>` with class **wrapper**, which is a flexbox.
- The card is made up of two elements, an image which is also a
  link, and content.
- The link `<a>`, class **link**, is positioned
  *relative*.
- The link consists of two sub-elements, a placeholder `<div>` class **blur** and an `<img>` class **pic** which is the clear image.
- Both are positioned *absolute* and have `width: 100%`, but class **pic** has a higher stack order, i.e., `z-index: 2`, which places it above the placeholder.
- The background image for the blurred placeholder is set via *inline style* in the HTML.

### Code

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  height: auto;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.link {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 2px solid #ddd;
}

.blur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}

.pic {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.pic:hover {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.text {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="link">
    <div class="blur" style="background: url('https://i.imgur.com/5SZI6qZ.jpeg') 50% 50% / cover;"></div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5SZI6qZ.jpeg" alt="Title" class="pic" />
  </a>

  <div class="content">
    <p class="text">Agendum dicendo memores du gi ad. Perciperem occasionem ei ac im ac designabam. Ista rom sibi vul apud tam. Notaverim to extendere expendere concilium ab. Aliae cogor tales fas modus parum sap nullo. Voluntate ingressus infirmari ex mentemque ac manifeste
      eo. Ac gnum ei utor sive se. Nec curant contra seriem amisit res gaudet adsunt. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fondo: url(/grid/assets/img/backimage.png);    
{ padding: 0; margin: 0; } 
body { 
    ::before{
        content:"" ; height: 1008px; width: 100%; display: flex; position: absolute; 
        background-image: $fondo ; background-repeat: no-repeat ; background-position: 
        center; background-size: cover; filter: blur(1.6rem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding explanation to your answer would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Q:Create the blur on parenttal div without effecting the child div -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    *{
        margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .parent{
background-image:url(hobby.jpg) ;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;

display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
    }
    .child{
   
    height: 90vh;
    width: 90vw;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.418);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    
 
    }
  .text{
    
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      border-radius: 500px;
      background-image: url(50cf380e5c78eb174faa8e6ac2cb654a.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      

  }
    
    
</style>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
       <div class="text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I didn't write this, but I noticed there was a polyfill for the partially supported `backdrop-filter` using the CSS SASS compiler, so if you have a compilation pipeline it can be achieved nicely (it also uses TypeScript):

https://codepen.io/mixal_bl4/pen/EwPMWo

Answer (score -1):

Without using the pseudo-class [from](https://css-tricks.com/apply-a-filter-to-a-background-image/)

```css
body{
    background:#cecece;
    font-family: "Scope One", serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:black;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-image: 
       linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.81)), 
        url(https://i.imgur.com/2rRMQh7.jpg);
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover; 
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a div over the image you want to apply the filter and use `backdrop-filter` to its CSS class.
Check out [this link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is [useful without it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). It's better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes and [answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score -2):

```css
div {
    background: inherit;
    width: 250px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;  /* Adding overflow hidden */
}

div:before {
    content: ‘’;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    left: -25px;  /* Giving minus -25px left position */
    right: 0;
    top: -25px;   /* Giving minus -25px top position */
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Steps to successfully apply the background image

1. ensure you've correctly linked your html and css using the link tag
   `<link rel="stylesheet" ref="yourcssdocument.css">`
2. I have no idea about relative and sub directories so I can't comment on it
3. The best method that worked for me is when I used a URL link in css

```
#yourcssdoc .image {
   background-image: url("paste your link here with the quotations")
}
```

Comment: you might have missed his question there buddy.  The issue is relating to the `blur` not working, not how to get the image to show.

Comment: i see.thanks for noticing it, I didnt know why i was receiving the negative votes.Well, i will comment carefully from next time.

Answer (score -6):

If you want to content to be scrollable, set the position of the content to absolute:

```
content {
   position: absolute;
   ...
}
```

I don't know if this was just for me, but if not that's the fix!

**Also** since the background is fixed, it means you have a *"parallax"* effect! So now, not only did this person teach you how to make a blurry background, but it is also a parallax background effect!

Comment: does not answer the question