# background-image selector css

Tags: html, css

I want to use a filters on some 
'background-image: url("http://blablabla.jpg");'

The problem now is that it also affects the typography etc. Cause I apply the filter on the div instead of the background-image.

Is it possible to have something like this in css:

```
background {
   filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(50%) contrast(100%);  
}
```

Or 'background-image' etc.
I tried multiple things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image-that-i-am-setting-with-ba Take a look at this.

Comment: You cannot apply filters or opacity to background images. You may need to re-think your HTML structure.

Comment: @Paulie_D we can apply.

Comment: @KawineshSK Not to **actual** background images...only inline images or pseudo-elements as you have suggested, The filter is **not** being applied to the background image itself.

Comment: @Paulie_D Cool !!!! i didn't get u clearly until you explained.

Comment: Thx for finding the duplicate, I knew there has to be one but I couldn't find one :)

Answer (score 0):

use Filter With Prefix

```
-webkit-filter:  grayscale(100%) brightness(50%) contrast(100%);
  -moz-filter:  grayscale(100%) brightness(50%) contrast(100%);
  -o-filter:  grayscale(100%) brightness(50%) contrast(100%);
  -ms-filter:  grayscale(100%) brightness(50%) contrast(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(50%) contrast(100%);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T5j6H/621/)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the filter prefix. Make your textfont white for example. It will become gray cause of the brightness filter.

Comment: @clankill3r no it wont check this out http://jsfiddle.net/T5j6H/623/

Comment: hmm, can you try to make the example work where the content is in a div with some class name? It fails when I try that. I either see nothing, or something not working.

Comment: @clankill3r you want the image to be in a div or body.

Comment: thanks! I was hoping you knew a way around but that's what I will do then.