# How do I recreate a web form like this without reducing the opacity of form elements?

Tags: css, forms, opacity, styling

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/io7NH.jpg]

I want to create a form similar to this on my website. Unfortunately, when I lower the opacity of the div conaining my form elements, the e-mail, password, and text all reduce in opacity as well. How can I make a form like this where only the surrounding box is see-through, but my login elements, title, and buttons are not?

Comment: Why don't you just inspect the style on that form and see how it was done?

Comment: I found this pic on Google images and am using it for inspiration purposes. I would like to recreate the styling effects, but unfortunately don't know what website it comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `div` with `background:rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.3 );` and than simply add the inputs which than could look somehow like this:

```css
.login_wrapper {
    width:300px;
    height:375px;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.3 );
    margin:0 auto;
}
.login_wrapper h1 {
    padding-top:30px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
}
.login_wrapper input[type=text] {
    width:80%;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background:url("https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1428591501234-1ffcb0d6871f?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&q=75&w=1050");
    background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="login_wrapper">
    <h1>Create Account</h1>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

I think you now get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the opacity of the background div using rgba. For example:

```
.form-container { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```

The last parameter for rgba is the alpha value and controls the transparency of the background.

Answer (score 0):

The surrounding box is not actually "see through" - you'll notice it actually contains a blurred version of the page's background image in addition to a lightened effect.

I feel the best way to achieve this, at the cost of dev-time, is to create two background images (the page's background, and a blurred, lightened version of the same in Photoshop) and set the `background-image` of the elements accordingly. You can use CSS's new `calc` function to help keep the images aligned if you're doing any advanced trickery.

The simpler approach, though considerably more CPU intensive on the web-browser and not supported by browsers older than a few years is to use CSS's `blur` filter. This is documented here: [How to apply a CSS 3 blur filter to a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image-that-i-am-setting-with-ba)

Answer (score 0):

The way I've always done this has been...

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-content">
      <h2>Whatever</h2>
      <form><!-- foo --></form>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.overlay-content` has a bg color (white to lighten, black to darken) such as `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);` with a transparency value.