# How to blur a banner photo in CSS Style?

Tags: html, image, css

So my banner is in a `.wrapper.style1` and I've used a webkit-filter to blur the photo but everything gets blurred the Nav Bar and the information inside the Banner. How could I fix this so only the image is being blurred?

Here is the  section of my CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    padding: 6em 0em 4em 0em;
}

    .wrapper.style1 {
        padding: 0em;
        background: url(../images/mlg.jpg); #222222 no-repeat;
        -webkit-filter: blur(10px);

        background-size: cover;
    }

    .wrapper.style2 {
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }

        .wrapper.style2 .major {
            text-align: left !important;
        }

            .wrapper.style2 .major h2 {
                display: block;
                margin-bottom: 0.70em;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
                line-height: 1.4em;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-size: 1.8em;
                font-weight: 400;
            }

            .wrapper.style2 .major .byline {
                letter-spacing: normal;
                line-height: 1.6em;
                text-transform: capitalize;
                font-size: 1.4em;
            }

        .wrapper.style2 h3 {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            line-height: 1.4em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 1.6em;
            font-weight: 400;
        }

    .wrapper.style3 {
        padding-bottom: 6em;
        background: #82b440;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }

        .wrapper.style3 .container {
            padding-left: 6em;
            padding-right: 6em;
        }

        .wrapper.style3 p {
            font-size: 1.6em;
        }

    .wrapper.style4 {
        background: white;
    }

    .wrapper.style5 {
        background: #82b440;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }

        .wrapper.style5 .image {
            display: block;
            width: 60%;
            margin: 0em auto 2em auto;
        }

            .wrapper.style5 .image img {
                border-radius: 50%;
                border: 10px solid;
                border-color: white;
            }
```

Here is a copy of some of the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>NueroEdge | Powered By Anazro</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script src="js/footage.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="homepage">

    <!-- Header Wrapper -->
        <div class="wrapper style1">

        <!-- Header -->
            <div id="header">
                <div class="container">

                    <!-- Logo -->
                        <h1><a href="index.html"  img src="images/NueroEdgeText.png" alt="NueroEdge" style="width:105px;height:55px">

                    <!-- Nav -->
                        <nav id="nav">

                            <ul>
                            <img src="images/NueroEdgeText.png" alt="NueroEdge" style="width:105px;height:55px">
                                <li class="active">
                                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                                <ul>
                                        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                                <li><a href="https://www.anazro.com/">Anazro Store</a></li>
                                <li><a href="left-sidebar.html">Application</a></li>
                                <li>
                                            <a href="">Roster</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#">Call Of Duty</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Streaming</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>

                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                            <li>
                                    <a href="">More...</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <!--<li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>-->
                                        <li>
                                    <a href="">LeaderBoard</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="">Ryan Tarson</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/ryantarson.png" alt="TECGaming" style="width:50px;height:50px">Ryan Tarson AKA: TECGaming</a></li>
                                                <li><Strong>Age:</Strong> 17</li>
                                                <li><Strong>Current Favourite Game:</Strong> Grand Theft Auto V PC</li>
                                                <li>I am Ryan Loves video games, computers and coding specifically Java, He plays really all types of</li>
                                                <li>games from a wide range and is willing to play any games from any genre to. He has a great and</li>
                                                <li>fun personality which would keep you hooked on his stream like it was a drug. Ryan is the type</li>
                                                <li>of streamer that is willing to do anything to keep his fans entertained. He has streamed before </li>
                                                <li>but never streamed seriously but planning to do so. I am the website Programmer as well!</li>
                                                <li>Click the links below and become apart of my life!</li>
                                                <div class="row double">                                            
                                                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/TECGaming360" class="button">Twitter</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/TECGaming360" class="button">YouTube</a></li>
                                                </div>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <br>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="">Kavin I.</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/profile.jpeg" alt="NueroEdge" style="width:50px;height:50px">Kavin I. AKA: KaVn Ne</a></li>
                                                <li><Strong>Age:</Strong> 16</li>
                                                <li><Strong>Current Favourite Game:</Strong> Advanced Warefare</li>
                                                <li>Kavin I. AKA KaVn Ne is Co-Founder along Side Ryan Tarson, Kavin loves video games</li>
                                                <li>mostly Call of Duty because that’s all he ever plays. He mostly plays all he</li>
                                                <li>ever plays. He mostly plays competitively and will stream singles matches or just</li>
                                                <li>random  hangouts with fans but he would play other games if Call of Duty  is down</li>
                                                <li> or someone requests something different. Kavin loves computers and any type of</li>
                                                <li>electronics for some odd reason. Kavin has a unique personality and which could</li>
                                                <li>make you become addicted to watching him play video games BEWARE!</li>
                                                <div class="row double">                                            
                                                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/KaVn_Ne" class="button">Twitter</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6RGgeacGovnYZko5ZFAZjg" class="button">YouTube</a></li>
                                                </div>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <br>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="">Nick Marchitelli</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/Praise.jpg" alt="Praise" style="width:50px;height:50px">Nick Marchitelli AKA: Praise</a></li>
                                                <li><Strong>Age:</Strong> 16</li>
                                                <li><Strong>Current Favourite Game:</Strong> N/A</li>
                                                <li>Player and Captain for NueroEdge Call of Duty eSports Team.</li>
                                                <br>
                                                <li>Usually plays the supportive role on the team and also calls most of the shots and plays since he</li>
                                                <li>is captain but everyone has their time to shine if no plays aren’t working.</li>
                                                <li>Hybrid player AR and SMG role.</li>
                                                <li>Currently in 16th place In North America for win on GameBattles</li>
                                                <li>Been Playing Competitive Since COD Ghost</li>
                                                <li>Won a few Online Twitter Tournaments with his team.</li>
                                                <li><Strong>Previous affiliations:</strong></li>
                                                <li>✦<Strong> Spectra eSports</Strong></li>
                                                <li>✦<Strong> Livid eSports</Strong></li>
                                                <div class="row double">                                            
                                                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Praise_Ne" class="button">Twitter</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="umggaming.com/livid-praise " class="button">UMG Gaming</a></li>
                                                </div>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <br>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="">Luke Pondillo</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/profile.jpeg" alt="nueroedge" style="width:50px;height:50px">Luke Pondillo AKA: Flusso</a></li>
                                                <li><Strong>Age:</Strong> 16</li>
                                                <li><Strong>Current Favourite Game:</Strong> N/A</li>
                                                <li>Player for NueroEdge Call of Duty eSports Team.</li>
                                                <br>
                                                <li>Usually plays the Objective role on the team he nice on the sticks with his spot on AR skills but</li>
                                                <li>also can use a SMG, which makes him a hybrid player. The kind of player who can step up when </li>
                                                <li>the team needs it.</li>
                                                <li>Been Playing Competitive Since COD Ghost.</li>
                                                <li>Won a few Online Twitter Tournaments with his team.</li>
                                                <li><Strong>Previous affiliations:</strong></li>
                                                <li>✦<Strong> Spectra eSports</Strong></li>
                                                <li>✦<Strong> Livid eSports</Strong></li>
                                                <div class="row double">                                            
                                                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/FlussoNe" class="button">Twitter</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" class="button">YouTube</a></li>
                                                </div>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <br>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="">Joseph Balasico</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/palm.jpeg" alt="palm" style="width:50px;height:50px">Joseph Balasico AKA: Palm</a></li>
                                                <li><Strong>Age:</Strong> 15</li>
                                                <li><Strong>Current Favourite Game:</Strong> N/A</li>
                                                <li>Player for NueroEdge Call of Duty eSports Team.</li>
                                                <br>
                                                <li>Usually plays the Slayer role on the team he is known to be getting 30+ kills in every respawn</li>
                                                <li>and He is a hybrid player where he can use an AR and a SMG. His slaying skill itself helps guide </li>
                                                <li>his team to victory.</li>
                                                <li>Like to use an AR and SMG which makes him a Hybrid Player</li>
                                                <li>Been Playing Competitive COD since COD Ghost.</li>
                                                <li>Won a few Online Twitter Tournaments with his team.</li>
                                                <li><Strong>Previous affiliations:</strong></li>
                                                <li>✦<Strong> Spectra eSports</Strong></li>
                                                <li>✦<Strong> Livid eSports</Strong></li>
                                                <div class="row double">                                            
                                                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/LiviD_Palm" class="button">Twitter</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" class="button">YouTube</a></li>
                                                </div>
                                                </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        </li>



                            </ul>
                                        <!--<li><a href="#">Veroeros feugiat</a></li>-->
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                        </nav>

                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- Banner -->
        <<div id="banner">

         <section class="container">
         <h2>NueroEdge</h2>
                    <span>NueroEdge Outstanding performance at MLG Event</span>
                    <p>Looking for more fantastic players for our team!</P>
                     <a href="application.html" class="button alt">Sign Up</a>

                </section>

            </div>



        </div>
```

Comment: Where are ".wrapper", ".wrapper.style1", ".wrapper.style2"… in your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this a few times before with several different solutions. What I found the most useful is using the ::before selector. You inherit every background-property you specified and apply the filter.

```
.wrapper.style1 {
    padding: 0em;
    background: url(../images/mlg.jpg); #222222 no-repeat;    
    background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper.style1::before {
    content = "";
    background: inherit;
    background-size: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Sadly, blur doesn't leave sharp edges, so you probably have to zoom in a bit to cover that up.

Comment: _“Sadly, blur doesn't leave sharp edges”_ – well, it wouldn’t actually _be_ a blur if it did … But a container element of appropriate dimensions with `overflow:hidden` should be able to fix that, if desired.

Comment: @CBroe I meant the edges of the ::before- and the parent element will not match up. So you have to trim 10px from the top, right, bottom and left to make them match up nicely.

Comment: @CBroe It is bluring content inside banner and also the image in nav bar appears but not in banner part!

Comment: @Tarson Maybe a better explanation of what you mean?

Comment: @GamerNebulae On the Nav Bar it works the nav bar isnt being blurred works fine but my banner shows the defult background color #222222 but no image in center. Also the content/text inside is being blurred! Is their a way I could make it unblur?

Comment: No, you can not “un-blur” anything. Such a filter works on the element you apply it to, and _all_ its contents. So if you want to blur only some very specific element, you have to apply the filter to that element only.

Comment: @CBroe say I wanted to blur a certain image?

Comment: @Tarson You should split the navbar and such from the blurred image.

Answer (score 0):

You can not apply filter to the container div. For that you either call the image using  tag or use different container div for image.

Use this stackoverflow question - [How to apply a CSS 3 blur filter to a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image)