# css blur technique only for the background

Tags: css

i want to blur the background image of this html code using css3 filter and please provide explanation.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student-login</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        body{

            background-image: url("background.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-form">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the content in this will not get blurred.

Comment: Why don't you just use an image which is already blurry?

Comment: How are you trying to blur anything?

Comment: because css3 has the option to blur out any images which is not blur.using photoshop to make every picture blur is too much hassle i guess @Matt Ball

Comment: [link](http://codepen.io/akademy/pen/FlkzB) @j08691

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not provided any attempt to solve his problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use two different containers, take a look here it will help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20039965/4298050

Comment: it said there has to be two container can i use one container as body and another as div? @samir

Comment: if you put a blur on the body all your content will be blurred, i think the best solution is to make a div that doesnt comport anything exept blurred elements, and another normal that contains your content @Ethereal soul