# How to blur only background and not content in Ionic/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to have a blurred background for my content.

So far I tried this:

```
.background-image {
  background-image: url('../img/background/image.jpg');
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -o-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

and then

```
<ion-view class="background-image">
   // header, content, footer etc
<ion-view>
```

But then I get the problem that the whole screen is blurred and not only the background as follows:

[image]

Comment: To blur only the background image, your HTML should look more like this: `<ion-view class="background-image"></ion-view> <div>header, content, footer</div>`

Comment: You have to put .background-image under the content, absolute positioned with lower z-index.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

put content out side the blurred div.

```
.background-image {
  background-image: url('../img/background/image.jpg');
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -o-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
}

<div class="background-image"></div>

<div>Content</div>
```

Comment: Any idea how to remove the white blur in the corners (should be a seperate question I know), but perhaps you know it quickly.

Comment: try dis css

.background-image {
  background: no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  left: -5px;
  top:-5px;
  bottom:-5px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  margin:-5px;

 }

Answer (score 3):

there is an other way come to my head which is add second `background-image`,
which in css3 you can have multi `background` for one element, and the second one can be a blur image, even with low quality , like this

in `sass`

```
#element
 background:
  image: url(/*first url*/), url(/*second url*/)
  size: auto auto /*first one*/, 100% 100% /* second one*/
```

i guess second will cover first or revers , you can try it out

Answer (score 2):

Put the image outside the other div... Like this:

```
<div class="background-image"></div>

<div class="content">
<p>Here goes your content</p>
</div>
```