# CSS top container blur but no inside container

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div containers. I want the top container to be blur and the container inside to be have opacity.
For some reason, both containers are blurred. Why?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8y1s8cd/)

This is my HTML and CSS:

```
<body>

<div class="page blurme">
    <div id="container">
        <p>blur background image with and opaque container</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
body, p {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.page {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    background: #222 url('http://www.hdwallpapersn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/nature-background-images2.jpg') no-repeat left top;
    background-size: cover;
}

.blurme {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px); -moz-filter: blur(5px); -o-filter: blur(5px); -ms-filter: blur(5px); filter: blur(5px);
}

#container {width: 500px; min-height: 3500px; margin: 0 auto; border: 5px solid red; background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);}
#container > p {color: white;}
```

Comment: As your #container div is inside your .blurme div, it will be blurred too. You should create two divs in the same level (not parent-child).

Comment: is this what you are trying to get https://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/b8y1s8cd/1/embedded/result/

Comment: the problem with all of the solutions is that if the inside container is big, like 2500px, than the background image doesnt fill the screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both containers become blurred because the `#container` element is in the `.blurme` element. If you want only your background to be blurred, then you can use to create two child elements. One with the blurred image. The other one is the opaque container having 2 children, the 1st child contains another image that can't be scroll and the other contains your text block that can be scroll. Set their `z-index`, adjust their `left` and their other styles if necessary.

```css
body, p {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
  
.page {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}

.blurme {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px); -moz-filter: blur(5px); -o-filter: blur(5px); -ms-filter: blur(5px); filter: blur(5px);
    background: #222 url('http://www.hdwallpapersn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/nature-background-images2.jpg') no-repeat left top;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: -200px; right: 0;
    z-index: -2;
}

.bg {
    background: #222 url('http://www.hdwallpapersn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/nature-background-images2.jpg') no-repeat left top;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: -15px; right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {width: 500px; min-height: 3500px; margin: 0 auto; border: 5px solid red; background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);}
#container > p {color: white;}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="blurme"></div>
 <div id="container">
        <div class="bg"></div>
  <p>blur background image with and opaque container</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have given you an example. I thought what you need is more complex. But anyway, if you only want the text to have the opacity then you can use this, create two child elements, one that `blur(5px)` and the other one that's not.

```css
body, p {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
  
.page {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}

.blurme {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px); -moz-filter: blur(5px); -o-filter: blur(5px); -ms-filter: blur(5px); filter: blur(5px);
    background: #222 url('http://www.hdwallpapersn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/nature-background-images2.jpg') no-repeat left top;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

#container {width: 500px; min-height: 3500px; margin: 0 auto; border: 5px solid red; background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);}
#container > p {color: white;}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="blurme"></div>
 <div id="container">
  <p>blur background image with and opaque container</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

JSFIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/b8y1s8cd/2/

HTML

```
<div class="page blurme"></div>
<div id="container">
    <p>blur background image with and opaque container</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
.page {
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #222 url('http://www.hdwallpapersn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/nature-background-images2.jpg') no-repeat left top;
    background-size: cover;
}
.blurme {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 5px solid red;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: i appreciate the help, but the problem with this solution is that if the inside container is big, like 2500px, than the background image doesnt fill the screen

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to go a different route and make the box so that it is always centered.

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8y1s8cd/5/) for you to see the difference.

I did a simple google search and got a basis off of stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20039965/1865179).

Here is the CSS I used:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.background-image {
    background-image: url('http://www.hdwallpapersn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/nature-background-images2.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
.content {
    border: 5px solid red;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    margin: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: white;
}
```