# Full background slider Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, background, slider, center

I need to make a FullScreen  Background Slider and blur it a little bit.
And in the center of the slider on the top layer will be long input field and some text.

Which slider you can suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

A google search yieled [Vegas](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/). It has blur transitions, but if you want a blur constantly, you can use [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image). And finally, [centering text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally). Vegas has a bunch of cool features with transitions and animations. Seems nice!