# How to make the rounded blured border for rounded profile picture in CSS

Tags: html, css

I need a css code for border blur inside of the image. Please see https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6KNa.jpg

```css
.effet {
 width: 400px;
 height: 125px;
 margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
}
.profile-box{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    border: none !important;
    padding: 19.5px 10px;
    display: block;
}
.min_cir{
border-radius: 50%;
}
.filtre--r {
    -webkit-mask: -webkit-radial-gradient( center, closest-side, transparent 30%, black 80%);
    -webkit-mask: radial-gradient( closest-side at center, transparent 50%, black 110%);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    mask: url('#mask-radial');
    filter: url('#filtre1');
 margin-top: -307px;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-box">
 <div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left" href="">
   <!--<img class="img-circle" src="">-->
   <div class="effet">
   <img class="min_cir" src="http://i.imgur.com/oH1698V.jpg">
   <img class="filtre filtre--r min_cir" src="http://i.imgur.com/oH1698V.jpg">
   </div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

It is worked but not like corrected blured border.. Its working with gradient style.. Can anyone help me to make the "Fixed border and rounded with blur" image in CSS Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You might want this. Just make the images position `absolute` and give `transform: scale(1.1);` to the blurred image.

```css
.effet {
 width: 400px;
 height: 125px;
 margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
}
.profile-box{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    border: none !important;
    padding: 19.5px 10px;
    display: block;
}
.min_cir{
border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.filtre--r {
    -webkit-mask: -webkit-radial-gradient( center, closest-side, transparent 30%, black 80%);
    -webkit-mask: radial-gradient( closest-side at center, transparent 50%, black 110%);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    mask: url('#mask-radial');
    filter: url('#filtre1');
 transform: scale(1.1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-box">
 <div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left" href="">
   <!--<img class="img-circle" src="">-->
   <div class="effet">
   <img class="min_cir" src="http://i.imgur.com/oH1698V.jpg">
   <img class="filtre filtre--r min_cir" src="http://i.imgur.com/oH1698V.jpg">
   </div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Highly agree with this answer, but I would also suggest swapping the images because right now the blurred one appears on top.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're almost there.
I would use two images for this solution;

Layer A | `z-index:1` 
A div with the `background-image` being the profile picture. I would then blur the image with css3 blur.

Layer B | `z-index:2`
Will be the profile pic on top of this one

Check out this stackoverflow question for some guidance. Your situation is quite similar. Good luck! 
[How to apply a CSS 3 blur filter to a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image)