# how to make the background blurry in html

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make my background image blurry but i can't featured it out. can you help me ? Thanks in advance .. here are my code.

here the code for the background images:

```
html { 
  background: url(bench-green-park.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed ; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:92%;
}
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.content:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  
  display: block;
  background-image: url('http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG');
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam erat in ante malesuada, facilisis semper nulla semper. Phasellus sapien neque, faucibus in malesuada quis, lacinia et libero. Sed sed turpis tellus. Etiam ac aliquam tortor, eleifend rhoncus metus. Ut turpis massa, sollicitudin sit amet molestie a, posuere sit amet nisl. Mauris tincidunt cursus posuere. Nam commodo libero quis lacus sodales, nec feugiat ante posuere. Donec pulvinar auctor commodo. Donec egestas diam ut mi adipiscing, quis lacinia mauris condimentum. Quisque quis odio venenatis, venenatis nisi a, vehicula ipsum. Etiam at nisl eu felis vulputate porta.</p>
  <p>Fusce ut placerat eros. Aliquam consequat in augue sed convallis. Donec orci urna, tincidunt vel dui at, elementum semper dolor. Donec tincidunt risus sed magna dictum, quis luctus metus volutpat. Donec accumsan et nunc vulputate accumsan. Vestibulum tempor, erat in mattis fringilla, elit urna ornare nunc, vel pretium elit sem quis orci. Vivamus condimentum dictum tempor. Nam at est ante. Sed lobortis et lorem in sagittis. In suscipit in est et vehicula.</p>
</div>
```

### Main Post

[How to apply a CSS 3 blur filter to a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image)

Comment: thanks.. this work.. but can i zoom out the background image?

Comment: **NOT WORK** in IE 11, FireFox (32), it is supported in:
Chrome 18+
Chrome for Android 25+
Safari 6+
iOS Safari 6+
Blackberry browser 10+

Answer (score 3):

Use `webkit-filter`,`moz-filter`, `o-filter`, `-ms-filter`, `filter` to work on all major **browsers**

```
  .background-img {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;

   -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
   -moz-filter: blur(5px);
   -o-filter: blur(5px);
   -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
 }
```

or

```
 body    { 
 background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
 }

 #wrap { 
 background: url(images/bgblur.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
 width: 500px; margin: 40px auto;
 }
```

Comment: this just make my text blurry above the background.. the background image is still not blurry

Comment: yeah.. all my <img> had been turn in blur but the background image still the same..

Answer (score 1):

```
.className {     
    webkit-filter: blur(10px);     
    filter: blur(10px);      
}
```