# How can I blur the "repeated" part of background image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking if there is way to blur the **repeated** part of a background image so that if it is background position'ed `center` than the side of image itself are blurry?

Comment: There is a way of blurring stuff with css but the support is terrible and it's really heavy for the browser. Another approach would be to use the canvas element to blur the repeated part but in this case I'd suggest you just make the background always expand to the size of the container https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: If you are bringing in an image that you want blurred then bring in a blurred version of the image. If you are not un-blurring the image at any point. Also you could fade it out a little bit by changing `opacity`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image

Comment: If this only has to be static and not animated or something, then I would simply go with [multiple background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds) - a blurry version that gets repeated, and on top of that the normal one, not repeated. No need to involve jQuery if you really want something that simple.

Comment: @CBroe now that's something I find helpful. Thanks!

Comment: O.k., I added it as a (short) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this only has to be static and not animated or something, then I would simply go with [multiple background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds) - a blurry version that gets repeated, and on top of that the normal one, not repeated. (`background-position` set to the same for both.)

No need to involve jQuery if you really want something that simple.