# blur without background image

Tags: css, cinnamon

I creating theme (for me) for Cinnamon and i want to get blur effect on cinnamon panel, but i don't know how to do that. I know how to get blur on this:

```css
.moreblur {
    position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;

  display: block;
  background-image: url(http://www.yosemitehikes.com/images/wallpaper/yosemitehikes.com-valley-winter-1366x768.jpg);
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;

  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -o-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="moreblur"></div>
```

But remember: i need to get blur on background image, not myself image.
Thanks.

Comment: use opacity:0.3(any value) in your .moreblur class.

Comment: You need to show us the code of what you have...not on what you don't have.

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image

Comment: @Paulie_D No, thats isn't duplicate. In him question he ask how to get blur on fixed image. Code? Whats to show, if my code haven't anything interesting for anybody, cause i'm decorate cinnamon, not my web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you cannot change your HTML structure to add a new `div` to which to add the `background-image` and the `blur` . you could use a `pseudo-element` like `:before`

see below snippet

```css
.moreblur {
  position: fixed;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
}

.moreblur:before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(http://www.yosemitehikes.com/images/wallpaper/yosemitehikes.com-valley-winter-1366x768.jpg);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -o-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  content:"";
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="moreblur">
  <p>
  I am NOT Blured
  </p>
   <p>
  I am NOT Blured
  </p>
   <p>
  I am NOT Blured
  </p>
  
</div>
```

let me know if it helps