# Unfixed/dynamic div shall blur the background image behind it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blurry

At my new website project I have a fullpage background image. Over this, there is a dynamic div. This div shall blur the background image. So that just behind the div, the background image is blurred. I've just found some solutions on the internet with fixed positions and something like that. But that's something I want to avoid, beacause it's a full dynamic and responsive site.

And the backdrop-filter I wan't to avoid aswell, because it is alsmot not supported. But I don't care about the older IE and so on. If it works in modern browsers it's ok.

**In short: unfixed/dynamic div shall blur the background image behind it.**

I know, that a lot of people asked related questions, but they are all old and so are the answers. I've searched the half internet on this questions, but couldn't find a modern/dynamic answer. I can't believe that there isn't a jquery trick or something like that, that does the job.

I'm realy grateful for every helpful answer!

[image]
To make it more clear I added a picture. The DIV in this case is dynamic.

Comment: Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image ?

Comment: We need to see your code to help you out..

Comment: @yuriy636 thanks for your comment, but no I want it just partial in the size of the dynamic div

Comment: @luissimo I added a picture to make it more clear. I dont think my code would help you, its not much atm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this great tutorial and some changings in the CSS I did it:

http://jordanhollinger.com/2014/01/29/css-gaussian-blur-behind-a-translucent-box/

And its all CSS only!