# CSS Background becoming blurred besides a div

Tags: html, css

Well, I searched a lot and everything that I find didn't work for me, like a curse, what I'm tryng to do is blur a background image when the person that is viewing the web page see the div, I started to make this page a short time ago, as soon as I started to try to learn CSS and JavaScript, so, what I've done is this:

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title> BIRL </title>
</head>
<body>



<div class="bg-img">

<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center><div class="botao"><a href="game.html"><img src="play.png" class="playButton"></a></div></center>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="info">
<h1 class="titles">Quem nós Somos?</h1>
<a class="macaco">Nós somos uma empresa totalmente responsável e profisisonal inclinada a satisfação de nossa clientela
Nossos produtos sempre foram, são, e sempre serão destinados a nossos clientes, (salve ronildo)</a>

<h1 class="titles">Qual é a nossa missão na terra?</h1>
<a class="macaco">Nossa missão é proporcionar a melhor qualidade de entreterimento sadio para a sua família e amigos afins,
todos os nossos jogos possuem uma qualidade exemplar e classificação livre, ou seje, eles podem ser jogados por qualquer pessoa
em qualquer idade e qualquer lugar do mundo, nós nunca utilizaremos palavras de baixo calão em nossas obras eletrônicas, isto
é um exemplo para os seus filhos.</a>

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: LemonMilk;
    src: url(LemonMilk.otf);
}
.playButton {
    width: 55%;
    height: 40%;
    z-index:2;
}
.game {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background:url('background.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.botao {
    float: rigth;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index:2;
}
.info::before {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('background-blurred.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    content: '';
    opacity: 1;
}
.info {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: LemonMilk, Verdana, Tahoma;
    padding: 70px;
    text-align: justify;

}
.titles {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
.macaco {
    color: #000000;
}
```

I want to make something like this: http://jordanhollinger.com/media/bmu-landing.png

Comment: You'll need to be more specific what you want to have happen, it's hard to understand based on your question so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [How to apply a CSS 3 blur filter to a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image)

Now, there is typo float: rigth. Also, there are a lot of unnecessary things in your code, but you are beginner. Keep practicing and everything will fall in its place eventually!

And, it is hard to decipher what you want exactly. 
" what I'm tryng to do is blur a background image when the person that is viewing the web page see the div,"

Do you mean, when DIV with the picture is visible?

Comment: I'll search for an example

Comment: I don't know if you'll have the patience to help me, but, I tryed and got this:   print1: http://prntscr.com/cd39ae  print2: http://prntscr.com/cd39ra  print3: http://prntscr.com/cd39x5