# How to change background-image properties inside class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `card-panel div` with background image, I want to use a filter(sepia) ONLY on the background image(it paints everything inside the div).

How to enter the background-image properties?

```
.card-panel {
   background-image: url("../img/d1f71749f.jpg");
   position: relative;
   filter: sepia(50%);
}

/* something like this:
   .card-panel background-image {
   filter: sepia(50%);
}
*/
```

Comment: You could use a separate class, then apply the background image and the filter to that class only so your HTML for the `<div>` would have 2 classes, one for some styles and the other purely for the background image

Comment: That is not possible - filters work on an element an all its content. You need to put the background image into a separate (pseudo) element, apply the filter on that, and position it behind your card element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply a CSS 3 blur filter to a background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image)

Comment: @CBroe thanks, I did not know that!

Answer (score 2):

Provide a child `div` inside a parent `div`, give `background-image` to the child `div`, and apply `filter: sepia(50%);` to the child `div`.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

.parent {
   position: relative;
}

.child {
   background-image: url("../img/d1f71749f.jpg");
   filter: sepia(50%);
}
```