# How to properly blur the required images

Tags: html, css, blur

I am trying to blur just the image of the background, but it seems that the result that I am getting is blurring the whole `div`

My code is the following:

```css
.profile-div {
  background-image: url("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_QtDFVR44S_Q/TTu95-aiCqI/AAAAAAAAA-k/jP65Ns2H-f0/s1600/camaleon2.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 12em;
}

.img-profile {
  height: 8em;
  width: 8em;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-div scale-image img-blur">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input style="display: none" type="file" accept=".png,.jpg" (change)="uploadProfilePicture($event)" #fileInput />
    <img *ngIf="imageURL" src="{{auxAuth.photoURL}}" class="pointer rounded-circle img-profile" (click)="fileInput.click()">
  </div>
</div>
```

What I expected was to blur the `img` of the div background, but it is also blurring the inside `img`. How could I change that?

I show my current result:

[image]

Comment: have you checked this post, seems to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image

Comment: It works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move the background image to a separate div, and wrap them both with a container:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-div">
    <div class="profile-div scale-image img-blur"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input style="display: none" type="file" accept=".png,.jpg" (change)="uploadProfilePicture($event)" #fileInput />
        <img *ngIf="imageURL" src="{{auxAuth.photoURL}}" class="pointer rounded-circle img-profile" (click)="fileInput.click()">
      </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.profile-div, .container-div {
   width: 100%;
   height: 12em;
 }

.profile-div {
  //example blur
 filter: blur(8px);
 -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}

.img-profile {
 position: absolute;
 top: 2em;
 bottom: 2em;
 height: 8em;
 width: 8em;
 border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Comment: If his application must works for all browsers, this `filter` property won't works for IE