# Background img blur - css

Tags: html, css, hover

Hello dear developers,

I want to blur the background image on hovering.but it does not work. Can anybody help me? i tried many ways.
This is a box and i wand to blur backgournd and show the text with hover-over-effect.
currently when the mouse is over the boxes, the following happens:
Either:
the Background becomes blur but the text does not appear
or:
The texts appear but background will not blur

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="kursContainer">
        <div class="BodyKurs">
                <h1>Body</h1>
                <picture>
                    <img src="../Kurse/img/body.webp" alt="zumba">
                </picture>
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2>Body</h2>
                <h3>Abnehmen - 6 Wochen</h3>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing     elit</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.kursContainer {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  justify-items: center;
  width: 122vmin;
  margin: 2vmin auto;
  align-items: center;

  grid-template-areas:
    "body body fatburn"
    "body body zumba"
    "yoga sixpack sixpack"
    "step sixpack sixpack"
    "backwork backwork tourde"
    "backwork backwork booty";
 }
 .BodyKurs{
   position: relative;
   width: 80vmin;
   height: 80vmin;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background-color: var(--schwarz);
   transition: transform 0.2s;
 }

.BodyKurs img{
   width: 80vmin;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
 .BodyKurs h1 {
   position: absolute;
   text-align: start;
   padding-left: 3vmin;
   bottom: 1vmin;
   color: var(--hellGrau);
   font-size: 8vmin;
 }

 .BodyKurs:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0px 4.6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.278),
     0 0px 15.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.411), 0 0px 69px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
   transform: scale(1.05);
   z-index: 2;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

  .overlay {
  width: 80vmin;
  height: 80vmin;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: var(--hellGrau);
  transition: 0.3s all;
  /* background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); */
  visibility: hidden;
   cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 5;
}
 .overlay:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}

picture:hover {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply a CSS filter to a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-filter-to-a-background-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:not(:hover)` style

**Example 1:**

```css
.wrap:hover img,
.wrap:hover img:not(:hover) {
    filter: blur(3px);
}

.wrap {
    width: 300px;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    display: none;
}

.wrap:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
    <span>
        <h1>Lorem</h1>
        <p>Text</p>
    </span>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="300px">
</div>
```

---

This example is a little more CSS but I think it's easier to understand. Used again `:not(:hover)` but this time on the span element.

**Example 2:**

```css
.wrap:hover img,
.wrap:hover span:not(:hover) {
    filter: blur(3px);
}

.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

.wrap:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
    <span>
        <h1>Lorem</h1>
        <p>Text</p>
    </span>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="300px">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful! :) Thank you for the Accepted Answer, if you want you can give and a positive vote to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `filter: blur()` on the psuedo class `:hover:before` in your CSS of your `img` tag. I used a `p` tag on the text content and set a `z-index` on the two elements as well. Effectively stacking the elements on top of each other.

The background will go on the `:before` and make sure to set the position to absolute and content to `''` (nothing). Height and width to 100% so it fills up the div it is stacking on.

[blur()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur())

[filter:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

```css
.image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.image:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/white-transparent-leaf-on-mirror-260nw-1029171697.jpg);
  z-index: -1;
}
.image:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
  filter: blur(20px);
}
.img {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.image p {
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <div class="image">
    <p>Some dummy text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try removing the picture tag from the body, and simply use CSS background image property. Set the background-color of overlay on hover in rgba units as shown below:

```
<div class="kursContainer">
        <div class="BodyKurs">
                <h1>Body</h1>
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2>Body</h2>
                <h3>Abnehmen - 6 Wochen</h3>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing     elit</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.kursContainer {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  justify-items: center;
  width: 122vmin;
  margin: 2vmin auto;
  align-items: center;

  grid-template-areas:
    "body body fatburn"
    "body body zumba"
    "yoga sixpack sixpack"
    "step sixpack sixpack"
    "backwork backwork tourde"
    "backwork backwork booty";
 }
 .BodyKurs{
   position: relative;
   width: 80vmin;
   height: 80vmin;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background-color: var(--schwarz);
   transition: transform 0.2s;
   background-image: url("../Kurse/img/body.webp");
 }

.BodyKurs img{
   width: 80vmin;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
 .BodyKurs h1 {
   position: absolute;
   text-align: start;
   padding-left: 3vmin;
   bottom: 1vmin;
   color: var(--hellGrau);
   font-size: 8vmin;
 }

 .BodyKurs:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0px 4.6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.278),
     0 0px 15.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.411), 0 0px 69px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
   transform: scale(1.05);
   z-index: 2;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

  .overlay {
  width: 80vmin;
  height: 80vmin;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: var(--hellGrau);
  transition: 0.3s all;
  /* background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); */
   cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 5;
}
 .overlay:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

picture:hover {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but that was not work for me. I don't know why.